# Using table variable instead of temp table makes query execution slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, temporary-tables, query-performance

I have a table with historical data about cars `AutoData` with combined clustered key `Cas` (DateTime) + `GCom` (Car ID). One record contains various indicators, like fuel level, vehicle state etc.

Intervals between individual records for one car in `AutoData` table are irregular, sometimes it is 120 seconds, sometimes few seconds, sometimes hours etc. I need to normalize the records for viewing, so that it shows one record per every 30 seconds.

I have the following script:

```
DECLARE @GCom int = 2563,
    @Od DateTime2(0) = '20170210', 
    @Do DateTime2(0) = '20170224'    

--Create a table with intervals by 30 seconds
declare @temp Table ([cas] datetime2(0))
INSERT @temp([cas])
SELECT d
FROM
(
  SELECT
      d = DATEADD(SECOND, (rn - 1)*30, @Od)
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Od, @Do)*2) 
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM
          sys.all_objects AS s1
      CROSS JOIN
          sys.all_objects AS s2
      ORDER BY
          s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) AS y;

--Create temp table
CREATE TABLE #AutoData (
    [Cas] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [IDProvozniRezim] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IDRidic] [smallint] NULL,
    [Stav] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Klicek] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Alarm] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MAlarm] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DAlarm] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Bypass] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Lat] [real] NULL,
    [Lon] [real] NULL,
    [ObjemAktualni] [real] NOT NULL,
    [RychlostMaxV1] [real] NOT NULL,
    [RychlostV2] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Otacky] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Nadspotreba] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Vzdalenost] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Motor] [smallint] NOT NULL
)

--Populate the temp table selecting only relevant AutoData records
INSERT INTO #AutoData
SELECT [Cas]
      ,[IDProvozniRezim]
      ,[IDRidic]
      ,[Stav]
      ,[Klicek]
      ,[Alarm]
      ,[MAlarm]
      ,[DAlarm]
      ,[Bypass]
      ,[Lat]
      ,[Lon]
      ,[ObjemAktualni]
      ,[RychlostMaxV1]
      ,[RychlostV2]
      ,[Otacky]
      ,[Nadspotreba]
      ,[Vzdalenost]
      ,[Motor]
FROM AutoData a 
WHERE a.GCom = @GCom AND a.cas BETWEEN @Od AND @do

--Select final data
SELECT t.cas, ad.malarm, ad.IDProvoznirezim, ad.Otacky, ad.motor, ad.objemAktualni, ad.Nadspotreba 
FROM @temp t
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 stav, malarm, otacky,motor, objemAktualni, Nadspotreba, IDProvoznirezim  FROM #AutoData a
                     WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas)<=CASE WHEN Motor>120 THEN Motor ELSE 120 END 
                     AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,  a.cas, t.cas)>-30 
                     ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas)>0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) ELSE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas)*-1) +120 END
) ad

DROP TABLE #AutoData
```

At the first I have tried to write the script with only one table variable @temp placing the condition `WHERE a.GCom = @GCom AND a.cas BETWEEN @Od AND @do` in the last select. The script took 39 seconds to execute.

When I have used `#AutoData` temp table to preload data subset in a temp table like it is shown in the script above, it dropped to 5 seconds.

Then I have tried to use a table variable `@AutoData` instead of `#AutoData` - but it took again much longer - 22 seconds.

`@temp` table has 40320 records and `#AutoData` table has 1904 records for this example. But suprisingly just using `#temp` table instead of `@temp` variable made the execution slow again.

I was suprised to see such differences using or not-using temp table/variable. Appearently SQL Server could not by itself optimize the insides of the OUTER APPLY clause.

But why there is such a big difference using table variables vs. temp tables? 
Is there any other way to know, what to use and not just trying it?

---

Execution plan with temp table #AutoData: 
[image: TempTable]

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1y2x2Zcg

Execution plan with variable @AutoData:
[image: Variable]

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1rAZnbqx

Comment: Could you post the execution plans for both the queries with the temp table and the ones with the table variable?

Comment: What is the key on AutoData (not the temp - the table) ?

Comment: @Paparazzi Original `AutoData` has a combined clustered key Cas + GCom as I have specified I believe.

Comment: Give the row_number() I posted a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in this part of your question:

> @temp table has 40320 records

In the execution plan, hover your mouse over the @temp table's scan. Compare the estimated number of rows versus the actual number of rows. (If you'd like to post the plan at http://PasteThePlan.com, we can give you more specific details. Disclaimer: that's my company's site.)

You're going to see that the estimated number of rows is really low.

SQL Server estimates that 1-3 rows will come back from a table variable (depending on your version of SQL Server, cardinality estimator, trace flags, etc.) This in turn gives you a really bad execution plan because SQL Server underestimates how much work it'll need from other tables, how much memory to set aside, etc.

Here are the two most popular ways to get a more accurate estimate:

- Try a temp table instead (and look at estimated vs actual rows in the plan)
- Use OPTION (RECOMPILE) on your query - which will get you a much more precise estimate, but with some very big drawbacks around plan cache visibility and CPU usage

To see me doing it live, watch the 1-hour [Watch Brent Tune Queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwGCPtga06U) (disclaimer: that's me, linking to a video of me) where I take a Stack Overflow query that uses a table variable, and tune it live in front of an audience at SQL Rally Norway.

Comment: Changing `@temp` to `#temp` makes the last select execute slowly again even with PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Changing #AutoData to @AutoData and adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` worked well.

Answer (score 1):

The query planner is more efficient with #temp.  On a table variable it only considers the first few rows.

Your table variable (and #temp if you use one) would likely benefit from declaring a primary key.

Put a key on #AutoData and only populate with necessary rows.

**Sort by key as you add rows**.

I suspect below can be optimized with a row_number()

```
SELECT t.cas
     , ad.malarm, ad.IDProvoznirezim, ad.Otacky
     , ad.motor, ad.objemAktualni, ad.Nadspotreba 
FROM @temp t
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 malarm, IDProvoznirezim, Otacky
                         , motor, objemAktualni, Nadspotreba   
               FROM #AutoData a
              WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) <= CASE WHEN Motor > 120 THEN Motor ELSE 120 END 
                AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas)  > -30 
              ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) 
                            ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.cas, a.cas) + 120 END
            ) ad
```

This is an attempt as row_number()

```
select * from 
( SELECT t.cas
       , a.malarm, a.IDProvoznirezim, a.Otacky
       , a.motor, a.objemAktualni, a.Nadspotreba 
       , row_nunber() over (partition by t.cas 
                            ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) 
                            ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.cas, a.cas) + 120 END) rn
    FROM @temp t  -- with primay key t.cas order by
    join AutoData a
      on a.GCom = @GCom 
     AND a.cas BETWEEN @Od AND @do
     AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas) <= CASE WHEN Motor > 120 THEN Motor ELSE 120 END 
     AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.cas, t.cas)  > -30 
) ad 
where ad.rn = 1
```

Comment: Adding PRIMARY KEY to @temp table slowed execution significantly... Another quite unexpected thing for me.

Comment: Could you add some sample link how to optimize this OUTER APPLY query with ROW_NUMBER, just a link to some similar query...?

Comment: I cannot find it but there was just a question on top 1 outer versus row_number().   It may be on stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451972/cross-apply-select-top-1-much-slower-than-row-number#comment72059376_42451972 A lot of stuff from OP is misguided but it does compare one to the other

Comment: I have not found any hints that ROW_NUMBER way should be faster than OUTER APPLY. Your query does inner join and returns only one row.

Comment: I had the partition by wrong.  Please try again.  Row_number() can be much faster in these situations.  How long did it take to run (even with the wrong answer)?

Comment: Yes, with left join and using the reduced #AutoData it is a bit slower than the original query, but seems to be working, thanks.

Comment: Wow, I thought it would be faster.  Worth a try.

Comment: Here someone claims that APPLY should be faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: OK, hope you go what you needed